# What is the correct way to achieve this Javascript loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a calendar using PHP to get my dates from a server and Javascript to do the front end math. From the server I'm using the following values to work with: Today's date, number of days in current month, and today's position in the week with reference to a Sun to Sat 0-6 convention. In order to find the first day of a given month, I have to work backwards from the current day which has known values.

The chart below shows what I'm trying to do with Javascript. A switch is when I change the pos variable back to 6(7 due to for loop problem) when I've hit 0 as I'm subtracting away from pos.

[image]

The problem is that when the for loop starts, the position of today's current day which is 5, is immediately subtracted by 1, when it shouldn't be until the next day which is 28 (previous).

By inserting delays (see the initialPos variable), I'm able to get the right value. This doesn't seem right, what is the right way to do this?

Here's a comparison of the outputs with and without delays.

With delay:

[image]

Without delay:
(without delay means I didn't add 1 to todayPositionWeek, and 7 is 6 for the reset pos counter)

[image]

```
<script>
    today = 29;
    todayPositionWeek = 5;

    // start the count with todayPositionWeek shifted by 1 to not count
    var initialPos = todayPositionWeek+1;
    var numSwitches = 0;
    var loopRan = 0;
    for (var i = today; i > 0; i--) {
        loopRan++;
        // initialPos is 6
        initialPos--;
        // after it is 5 on first run
        if(initialPos == 0) {
            // reset pos counter
            initialPos = 7;
            // initially this was set to 6 but skips to 5
            numSwitches++;
        }

    firstDayPos = initialPos;

    }
    alert('loop ended ' +  firstDayPos + ' ' +  numSwitches + ' ' + loopRan);
</script>
```

Today it's fine, but if the day is off(today is not on Friday), the shifted days are off...

[image]

Comment: not exactly sure what you are trying to do here. can't you make use of javascript's builtin Date class.  It's a little basic/annoying to use, but it may serve your purposes here.  Or maybe you can just use integer arithmetic of some kind (mod, floor etc.)?

Comment: @dan-man, I've shown what I'm trying to do, the chart is what I'm trying to accomplish. PHP gives me some known values based on today's date. I'm determining the values to fill the calendar with. The problem is that the loop is not straight forward, I have to edit it by adding a "delay" because of how the for loop runs. This works right now, does the job, I'm saying it sucks, it's not right. This is a "hack" or a piece of crap. This is a complete calendar too not just today's date.

Comment: i still don't really get it, but aren't you just doing something like `(a-b) % 7`?

Comment: @dan-man It is confusing, on any given calendar there are usually days from the previous month which shift in the current days of this month. I don't know where the first month is with regard to a grid. So I have to determine on what day Sun-Sat the first of the month occurs, then I can determine how many days from last month I have to shift in.

Comment: @dan-man I actually am/was using a mod function. Although I'm not sure if I need to anymore. My first attempt at this, the calendar only worked on the weeks where today is Friday so wehn today was 22, 15, 8, 1, the calendar was perfect (days shifted in) but any other days it was off.

Comment: This seems like an X/Y problem.  Are you trying to lay out a calendar (like a normal 5-6 week by 7 day grid)?  What is your desired result here?

Comment: @IanMcLaird, Yeah I'm trying to lay out a 7x5 grid. I've set it up already, but it doesn't work correctly, eg. if today is not on Friday, the shifted days are off. I'm going to keep at it, I'm just trying to learn how to do things the right way. I'll attached an image of the current version.

Comment: I think I'd take a different approach.  Figure out what day of the week the first of the month is, then loop backward until you find a Sunday (unless you started on one), and then loop forward until the Saturday after (or equal to) the last day of the month.  You'll need two loops, but they should be easier loops to write.

Comment: @IanMcLaird That is the approach I'm doing as far as "figuring out what day of the week the first of the month is". Then I get the number of days from the previous month, subtract from the end, how many days have to be shifted in before the start of the current month. It's just my loop structure sucks, I'm wondering if I should use other loop structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var today = 27;
var todayPositionWeek=3;

var offset = (toDayPositionWeek+7-(today%7))%7  // ==4  because day0 ==4

function posOfAnyDay(d) {
  return (offset + d) % 7;
}
function slotOfAnyDay(d) {
  return Math.floor((offset + d) / 7);
}

//  posOfAnyDay(13)  ->  3
//  slotOfAnyDay(13)  ->  2

for (var i = today; i > 0; i--) {
  pos = posOfAnyDay(i);
  slot = slotOfAnyDay(i);
}
```

Comment: I'm so lost right now, just going over my own code, I'm not even sure about your code. No offense meant, I'm just saying I'm not able to follow, not even sure what I was asking but thank you for your answer.